# R package for Bayesian generalized non-linear model

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model, jags, stan

I would like to know if it is possible to fit the Lee-Carter model in a Bayesian setting.

This model is used to forecast population mortality dynamics and has the following form:
$$ log(\mu_{xt})=\alpha_x+\beta_x \kappa_t ,$$
where $\beta_x $ and $\kappa_t $ are factors for age and year, respectively. Due to the multiplication of predictors, this model does not fit in the GLM framework and cannot be fitted with the **stan_glm** function of the **rstanarm** package. In the frequentist setting, this model can be fitted with the **gnm** package but I couldn’t find a Bayesian equivalent.

Do you know if there is a Bayesian equivalent to the gnm package? Or should I define a stan model with specific priors and likelihood function?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The answer to questions of the form "I would like to know if it is possible to fit the [some] model in a Bayesian setting." is typically affirmative if you only mean is it possible to write down a generative process under the model and then condition on observed outcomes. Whether it can be fit in finite time is an empirical question. I highly doubt there is an R package that currently implements a Lee-Carter model, and questions about how to find or write code for a particular model are considered off-topic on CrossValidated. If you ask on https://discourse.mc-stan.org/, I will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, this should be possible to fit in a Bayesian setting but I am new to Stan and on how to write code for this specific model within the stan language. I have made a post on mc-stan as well: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/bayesian-estimation-for-association-models-with-multiplicative-predictors/13861 but no answer for the moment. Thanks for your help!